# Formando nova imagem a partir de uma area map

Tags: html, html5, img

Boa tarde, estou fazendo um projeto onde o site da empresa é um sinótico e nesse sinótico é gerada imagens a cada 8 segundos. (obs: ainda preciso saber um modo de pegar essas imagens e passar para o meu projeto).
O que fiz até agora foi um teste com qualquer imagem, o programa em html, java e php. Primeiramente quando coloco a imagem consigo pegar os dados dessa imagem e transformar em texto. Eu, queria pegar somente uma área dessa imagem e  pegar esse texto, tentei usar o "map" "area" com as coordenadas que quero.

A tag map>area interpreta como imagem?
O que eu poderia fazer para pegar somente  "area" do map? A tag area map só serve para passar o mouse em cima? ou para poder clicar? teria outra forma?

Comment: Forneça um exemplo minimo,  sim, pode se clicar em uma imagem mapeada https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp nesse link ensina como mapear uma imagem em html; Aqui tem como você manipular com um pouco de js: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_map.asp

Comment: Coloca o codigo teste do que você já fezfez, em uma area map você pode definir essa area como clicável, colocar um link para outra imagem da sequencia, pertencente aquela area.